# How to hide a window's toolbar temporarily

Tags: linux-mint, mate-desktop, window-decorations

How would I temporarily hide the toolbar on programs' windows:

[image]

Surly there must be a way to do this with MATE?

I tried Google and I got unrelated issues.

Comment: Are you talking about the Toolbar or, as your red marks indicate, the Menubar?

Comment: The menubar.  Is that probably why I couldn't find a solution? Lol.

Comment: Maybe; most applications have an option to hide it in their preferences, and then tapping the ALT key shows it.

Comment: Most of the applications I want to hide it on don't,  *sigh*.  I also tried right clicking the title thing itself, and there was no option in the context menu either.